# How I can get a cross compiler under Ubuntu for sparc target?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu, cross-compiling

How I can get a cross compiler under Ubuntu for sparc target?

I want to compile my c and c++ program, working in Ubuntu, for sparc architecture? How i can do this? Can I use mingw32 cross compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile a gcc cross compiler.  The first step is to download the source code for gcc, bin-utils (gnu as, ld, etc), and the standard library for the platform.

Once you have the necessary source code(s) you need to configure, make, and then install the cross compiler without clobbering your host gcc.

```
./configure  --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX
make
make install
```

Rinse and repeat for bin-utils.  I believe you'll have to pass in the location of the source for the standard library to configure, but I don't know what the argument is.  I've just done this for OS dev where you don't really need it.  Look into newlib if you're having trouble with this.

$TARGET is obviously the target platform, for you it'll be a string like sparc-elf or sparc64-elf, but it depends.

$PREFIX is where your cross compiler will be located.  It will be named something like $TARGET-gcc.  So this is optional, just make sure it ends up on your path.

http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.6.2/

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/

http://sourceware.org/newlib/

Answer (score 3):

The "W" in "MingW" stands for Windows, so no you can not use that.

Check out [this page](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cross-compile.html) on how to make a GCC version that cross compile to SPARC.

Answer (score 1):

Build it yourself from sources or download prebuilt binaries, for example from [here](http://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/Downloads?tm=2#Tools) or from [here](http://www.gaisler.com/cms/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=161&Itemid=109).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use one of the cross compilers from [emdebian](http://www.emdebian.org/).

If you get strange errors about missing includes, then you stumbled over a version where the dependency on the kernel headers is missing, in this case you need to manually install `linux-libc-dev-sparc-cross` as well.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways of obtaining a working cross compiler for Sparc V8 is to use Buildroot. [Here's a small tutorial](https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/course/~nehak/SparcQemu.html) on installing the cross compiler and testing the executables on Qemu emulator.